# Problema con las rutas laravel acabadas en /?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un problema con una app en laravel, en locahost funciona todo perfecto, el problema viene cuando lo subo a ionos,  parece que todo funciona el problema es que las url solo funcionan sin / al final, Ejemplo

[www.test.com/user](http://www.test.com/user) -> Funciona

[www.test.com/user/](http://www.test.com/user/) - No funciona

He creado un archivo .htacess en la carpeta raiz con lo siguiente

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Y otro dentro de public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

La archivo web.php de las rutas

```
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/especialidades', 'especialidadesController@index');
Route::get('/atencion-a-domicilio', 'atencionController@index');
Route::get('/{localiad}/{slug}', 'AnuncioController@post')->name('post');
Route::get('/salir', 'HomeController@logout');

Route::get('/politica-de-cookies', function () {
    return view('web/politica');
});

Route::get('/terminos-y-condiciones', function () {
    return view('web/terminos');
});

Route::get('/contact', 'ContactController@contactUs');


Route::post('contact',[


    'as'=>'contact.store',
    
    
    'uses'=>'ContactController@contactUsPost'
    
    
    ]);

Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
        $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
        return 1;
});

// backend
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/tus-anuncios', 'BackController@index')->name('perfil');
```

Lo que me fijado es que cuando escribes / al final te redireciona al home.

A alguien mas le pasa?

Answer (score 0):

Si, no sé la razón pero no utilizo / al final porque genera problemas, entiendo que hay que tomarlo como norma, y listo.

Comment: Tengo otro proyecto donde pobre laravel y si que funciona con / al final

Comment: Donde más me complicó fue en rutas get que traían datos de la BD, con / no andaba, sin / anduvo.